# cómo instalar R Java en R studio, aparece error en la instalación

Tags: r, rjava

> package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.2Error: package ‘rJava’
>   could not be loaded

Ya descargué la nueva versión de Java tanto 64 bits como 32, ya actualicé R y reinicié equipo y sigue apareciendo ese error, ayuda por favor!!

Comment: Bienvenida, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], con repecto a tu pregunta,  `‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.2` es un warning que puedes ignorar, no un error, sin embargo `Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded` si es un error, el tema es que normalmente debiera haber más detalle. Podrías revisar esto y agregar a tu pregunta cualquier mensaje adicional? Puedes probar lo que te digo haciendo: `library(rJava)`, además sería útil que pegaras la salida del comando `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Si suiges con el error intenta seguir los pasos de este link que, por lo menos a mi, me ha ayudado: https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer#installing-java-on-windows-with-chocolatey